# Excel IF statement #NAME? error too many statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is the statement I am working on to calculate values based on two criteria and 'if' statements. 
I have tried to use nested 'if' statements but they will not let you use two criteria for each statement.
Is there another way to get around this?

`=IF(AND(S2 = Yes, N2>5%), 5%*L2, N2*L2, 
IF(AND(S2 = No, N2>5%),((U2/T2)*5%)*L2,  ((U2/T2)*N2)*L2))`

With everyone's help I was able to adjust the formula to: =IF(AND(S2="Yes",N2>5%),5%*L2,IF(AND(S2="No",N2>5%),((U2/T2)*5%)*L2,IF(AND(S2="No",N2<5%),((U2/T2)*N2)*L2,N2*L2)))

Added one additional IF statement to get the last criteria I needed.

Comment: please explain the logic in words, it will help us.  What is the requirement for each of the 4 outputs?

Comment: Unless you have defined names as *Yes* and *No* you need to use `"Yes"` and `"No"`.

Comment: And also as the error says, you have too much arguments. the IF() function only takes 3, you have 4. Maybe the 'N2*L2' at the end of the first line should have another if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking out the N2*L2, and adding Jeeped suggestion:

=IF(AND(S2 = Yes, N2>5%), 5%*L2, **N2*L2,**
=IF(AND(S2 = No, N2>5%),((U2/T2)*5%)*L2,  ((U2/T2)*N2)*L2))

```
=IF(AND(S2 = "Yes", N2>5%), 5%*L2,  IF(AND(S2 = "No", N2>5%),((U2/T2)*5%)*L2, ((U2/T2)*N2)*L2))
```

Again, you need to clarify your requirement.

Comment: The first part is checking to see if the row has a yes in it and the contribution amount is over 5% So I was wanting the calculation 5%*L2 if that is true and N2*L2 if false. The second part is checking for rows with No and over 5% and it gives them the partial match if true and partial match amount if false.

Comment: I believe your formula will work I may just have to use N2*L2 at the end depending on the results with my data.

Answer (score 0):

If Statment Layout

if(A+B=C,True,False)  this is a basic if statment.

if(A+B=C,True,if(G+H=X,True,False))  this is a nested if statment.

replacing the first False with the next if statment but remember to add an end bracket for each nested if statment at the end of your final one.

an example of one I used before below, it can get a bit confusing with so many nested statements , but I can assure you this formula works in my sheet.

=IF(B9=0,IF(OR(C9=0,D9=0),0,IF(AND((C9*D9)<1,(C9*D9)>0.001),MROUND(((C9*D9)*1000),0.001)&" mV",IF((C9*D9)<0.001,MROUND(((C9*D9)*1000000),0.001)&" uV",MROUND((C9*D9),0.001)&" Volts"))),(IF(C9=0,IF(OR(B9=0,D9=0),0,IF(AND((B9/D9)<1,(B9/D9)>0.001),MROUND(((B9/D9)*1000),0.001)&" mA",IF((B9/D9)<0.001,MROUND(((B9/D9)*1000000),0.001)&" uA",MROUND((B9/D9),0.001)&" Amps"))),IF(D9=0,IF(OR(B9=0,C9=0),0,IF(AND((B9/C9)<1,(B9/C9)>0.001),MROUND(((B9/C9)*1000),0.001)&" mΩ",IF((B9/C9)<0.001,MROUND(((B9/C9)*1000000),0.001)&" uΩ",MROUND((B9/C9),0.001)&" Ohms"))),"Leave Desired Quantity Empty"))))

the above formula is used to calculate Ohms Law from 2 out of 3 value cells, it also rounnds the figures to the appropriate value size , ie adding Ohms, Mega or Giga to the value  (93 ohms) or (93 Mega) or as the answer required Volts Or Amps